# Parallel Binary Search (easy implementation)

Tags: algorithm, c++11, parallel-processing, binary-search-tree

Not sufficient material to learn about parallel binary search available .
some posts directly explain through problems that are not  easy to strike at first. please give easy explanation ?

Comment: Did you find something? Please share with us what you already know about this.

Comment: currently referring to  link  http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/45578

Comment: "Not sufficient material" - what have you done? I'm sure that something like the IEEE Transactions on Parallel and Distributed Systems (for instance - google gives me two hits there at the top of my search).

Comment: Well the link you mentioned is the best source to learn this thing from!